# How to get tweets including my tweets with 1query by Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I’m building like Twitter to learn Laravel.

I want to get the information of Tweets which I follow, and including my Tweets with 1 query.

This is the model of relationships.
Please check, I only take the information about relationships.

[image]

Please give me advice.

Follow Model
    class Follow extends Model {

```
Public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "followed_user_id", "id");
}}
```

Tweet Model

```
class Tweet extends Model {

Public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "user_id");
}}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Model{

Public function tweet(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tweet::class);
}
Public function followUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Follow::class, "follow_user_id");
}
Public function followedUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Follow::class, "followed_user_id");
}}
```

Comment: you need to wire up relationships first in you models

Comment: @Flash Yes, I did..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the users with his all the tweets you can simply use

```
User::with('tweets')->get();
```

If you want to get the tweets of a single user in a single query you can

```
User::with(['tweets' => function($query) use ($userId){

     $query->where('user_id', $userId);

}])->first()
```

Comment: hm? this seems just find user_id is $userId...
I mean want to get the user's following tweets, including the user's tweets.
For example, I follow the peoples and get all tweets of them and plus, including my tweets.

Comment: @YOSUKE please post your models

Comment: could you see the pictures I attached?

Comment: @YOSUKE I can see these but post your model classes too.

Comment: I added, Please check @Adnan Mumtaz